# convert a jpg/png/txt or any file format to pdf using mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, asp.net-mvc-5

How do i convert a jpg/png/txt or any file format to pdf using mvc c#.
Here is the code:

```
 public ActionResult SaveProfileDocument(string code)
        {
            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
            string fName = "";
            string _documentname = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                    //Save file content goes here
                    fName = file.FileName;
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {

                        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Documents\\Profile\\" + code, Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString());

                        var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                        bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);

                        if (!isExists)
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                        _documentname=fName;

                        var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {
                            _documentname=Guid.NewGuid()+"_"+file.FileName;

                            var path2 = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString,_documentname );
                            file.SaveAs(path2);
                        }
                        else {
                            file.SaveAs(path);
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSavedSuccessfully = false;
            }


            if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Json(new { Message = fName, documentname = _documentname });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file", documentname=""});
            }
        }
```

In the above code i am saving the file.but
here i need to convert the file and then save.

so for convert i need a separate class or method here only call that method.

The thing is that while upload a file inthat time need to convert pdf any file to convert pdf. and save in folder or whatever.

Comment: I don't know what your question is. What specifically are you stuck at?

Comment: i need to convert jpg format file to pdf using c#

Comment: You don't convert a JPG file to a PDF. A JPG is an image format. A PDF is a document format. You can create a PDF and then insert a JPG into it. You'll likely need a library capable of generating a PDF. I suggest you research and find one that works with .NET and read up on its documentation.

Comment: i need to convert any format to pdf it may be the jpg or png or txt ot xlx or jpeg whatever

Comment: why i can't convert??my requirement is something if suppose choose pdf then its okay if any one choose any other format then convert it to pdf

Comment: Then you will need to research how to embed these types of data using whatever library you choose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142620/discussion-between-manoj-maharana-and-mason).

Comment: Is there any possibility to convert??

Comment: @mason you don't know how to do but why send me negative ratings..

Comment: As I pointed out in our chat, it's far more important for you to learn how and research than for me to just give you the code.

Answer (score 0):

can't convert an image file to PDF. You can create a PDF file and add the image file to it:

```
string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Images");
Document doc = new Document();
try
{
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Images.pdf", FileMode.Create));
  doc.Open();

  doc.Add(new Paragraph("GIF"));
  Image gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/mikesdotnetting.gif");
  doc.Add(gif);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Log error;
}
finally
{
  doc.Close();
}
```

here i am refer:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images